# How do I commit to my README file on Gitpod?

Tags: commit, git-commit, readme

Please pardon my possibly quite simple question. But how do I commit my changes to my README file on Gitpod? When I do git add . and then git commit -m "text" it just says "nothing to commit, working tree clean"?

Comment: What does `git status` say? Does it show the changed file as staged?

Comment: Where you in the right directory when you ran `git add .`?  It says "add change files in this directory or below".  If the change file is elsewhere it is not added.